# pandas Python - How to get a correct format in Excel from a JSON file

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas

Hope you are safe :)

I am using Python 3.6.3 and my version of pandas is 0.23.0.

I cannot update to a higher version of Python since the corporate version of my company is Python is 3.6.1 (pandas version is 0.20.1).

I cannot manage with restitution of data JSON format using :

```
   EXCEL_request = (destfile_dir_EXCEL + '\\TEST_Request.xlsx')

   writer = pd.ExcelWriter(EXCEL_request, engine='xlsxwriter')

   df_request.to_excel(writer,'Request from JSON', index= None)

   writer.close()
```

I have two JSON files to write to Excel.

The first file JSON format is as below :

{

```
"values": [{
        "name": "Data1",
        "values": ["0"]    # list format
    }, {
        "name": "Data2",
        "values": ["N"]    # list format
```

and so on
...

Through pd.to_excel(), I get the following format as a result in Excell cell:

```
        Col1                   Col2              Col3
        Data_1                  FE              ['0']
        Data_2                  FE              ['N']
```

which is not the correct format (Col3).

Desired format is :

```
        Col1                   Col2              Col3
        Data_1                  FE                0
        Data_2                  FE                N
```

The second JSON file format is as follows :

```
       {
"data": {
    "queries": [{
            "id": 292,
            "name": "Data_1",
            "queryId": 0,
            "values": {
                "Entreprise": {
                    "F1": {
                        "rule": 1450,
                        **"value": "1.000000000000"**
                    }
                }
            }
        }, {
            "id": 430,
            "name": "Data_2",
            "queryId": 1,
            "values": {
                "Entreprise": {
                    "F1": {
                        "rule": 1437,
                        **"value": "N"**
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    and so on
```

Still using:

```
   EXCEL_response = (destfile_dir_EXCEL + '\\TEST_Response.xlsx')
   writer = pd.ExcelWriter(EXCEL_response, engine='xlsxwriter')
   df_response.to_excel(writer,'Response from JSON', index= None)
   writer.close()
```

--- >>  the Excel format is correct (Col3) :

```
        Col1                   Col2              Col3
       Data_3                    DC         1.000000000000
       Data_4                    DC         N
```

I dont know how to get this correct format from the first file.

Thank you for your time and your help.

Greetings from Paris, France :)

Comment: After loading your first file to pandas DF use pandas apply with a lambda to take out those brackets, the must efficient way should be a regex, but python str function should also work fine. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Comment: You can normalize the JSON before using pandas `json_normalize` function
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20.1/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html

Comment: @Carlos P Ceballos , thank you for your help. I found a solution which meets my needs concerning the desired format. I am using pandas since 18 months, but JSON is a very quite new topic for me. I will soon post what I have done.        Thanks again and greetings from Paris, France

Comment: @Bhavani Ravi, Thank you for your help. I did try " json_normalize"   function. I opted for a quick and "harmless" solution to get the job done. As I told Carlos in my comment above, I will post soon my code. Thank you and greetings from Paris, France :)